# mlflow serving r models failed if use LDA instead of linear regression

Tags: r, mlflow

I have a mlflow question regarding to serve R models, below is my code to train and serialize the R model.

```
library(mlflow)
library(caret)
library(carrier)

set.seed(101)
sample <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
iris_train <- iris[sample,]
iris_test <- iris[-sample,]


with(mlflow_start_run()  , {
  control <- trainControl(method='cv', number=10)
  metric <- 'Accuracy'

  # Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA)
  model <- train(Species~., data=iris_train, method='lda', trControl=control, metric=metric,
                preProcess=c("center", "scale"))
  fn <- crate(~ caret::predict.train(model, .x), model = model)
  # fn <- crate(~ stats::predict(model, .x), model = model)
  iris_prediction <- predict(model, iris_test)

  mlflow_log_model(model = fn, artifact_path="model")
})
```

However, when I serve it with the API request,

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:5000/invocations' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"columns": ["Sepal.Length", "Sepal.With", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"], "data": [[5.2, 4.1, 1.5, 0.1], [6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.1], [7.9, 3.8, 6.4, 2.0], [6.7, 3.1, 5.6, 2.4], [6.3, 3.4, 5.6, 2.4]]}'
```

I have the following error:
`Invalid Request.  object 'Sepal.Width' not found`

Note, if I change the training to use linear regression model,

```
with(mlflow_start_run(), {
  model <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, iris)
  mlflow_log_model(
    crate(~ stats::predict(model, .x), model=model), "model")
})
```

The same API request, everything works fine.

Can anyone help me find any clue? I am not that familiar with R.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out the issue is a typo in curl script. it's Sepal.Width not Sepal.With.

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:5000/invocations' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"columns": ["Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"], "data": [[5.2, 4.1, 1.5, 0.1], [6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.1], [7.9, 3.8, 6.4, 2.0], [6.7, 3.1, 5.6, 2.4], [6.3, 3.4, 5.6, 2.4]]}'
```